# How can I turn off "middle mouse button paste" functionality in all programs?

Tags: xorg, mouse

I don't like having the middle mouse button paste, because I often end up with uncompilable code in Eclipse. How can I turn this off (in all programs)? I'm running Fedora.

Comment: Middle-click to insert selection is fundamentally part of the way X11 works; see [http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).

Comment: I've not seen any trivial way to do this without nuking the middle mouse button altogether or hacking X or screwing with the normal clipboard as well, so my suggested "solution" is just to learn to use the middle mouse button properly.  It's incredibly convenient to be able to highlight a text URL anywhere and go to it by middle clicking in my (FF) browser window.

Comment: @ephemient "Middle-click to insert selection is fundamentally part of the way X11 works" ... way back when we had Sun Optical Mouses that needed about 1 pound of pressure on the middle button to get signal. Today the middle button is on hair trigger and moreover used as a wheel, this "fundamental" has to go (as quite a lot of "fundamental" stuff in X btw.)

Comment: I feel like the ability to disable whatever you want is an even more fundamental aspect of Linux.

Comment: Step 1: write complex software for 5h, step 2: try to complie.. Ooops, something goes really wrong.. Step 3: check your code for 1h.. Step 4: Find you inserted code in a header by pressing middle-click. Conclusion: Middle click paste needs to go!

Answer (score 86):

This solution will work globally and preserve the middle mouse functionality under Xorg.

1. Install `xbindkeys xsel xdotool`
2. Place this in `~/.xbindkeysrc`

   ```
   "echo -n | xsel -n -i; pkill xbindkeys; xdotool click 2; xbindkeys"
   b:2 + Release
   ```
3. Reload `xbindkeys -p`

Run `xbindkeys` on startup, `pkill xbindkeys` to stop.

Comment: Is there way to disable only "paste" feature, but leave working others like browser "open link in new tab", "close tab", etc.. ?

Comment: @spiil I tried this solution and it achieves the effect you want. I middle-clicked in a text field and nothing happens, but middle-clicking on a link and middle-clicking to close a tab work in Chromium, Firefox, and Waterfox (the three browsers I tested).

Comment: Scrolling by click-and-hold middle button no longer works with this solution :/

Comment: I have been looking for a way to do this for years. So I was very happy seeing this  answer but unfortunately it does not work for me. Any idea what might be wrong. Is it correct that I have to create ~/.xbindkeysrc myself? None was created during the installation. I thought that maybe my middle mouse button was not b:2. But I think it is since pressing the middle mouse button in xev gives:
"ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x240, subw 0x0, time 15972433, (105,113), root:(1029,535),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES"

Comment: In order to get this to work I had to remove "+ Release". So if people are having trouble with the above solution give that a try. (And maybe this can be added to the answer).

Comment: Wouldn't that have the side effect of also killing every running process of yours with "xbindkeys" in the name? Might seem kind of far fetched for there to be any such process running other than the one you want to kill, but what if you have an xbindkeys-related script (perhaps even this one) where you put that in the name? I wonder if using a systemd service file and `systemctl --user stop` instead would be efficient.

Comment: nowadays I use https://github.com/milaq/XMousePasteBlock, which appears to use the same basic technique as this, but packaged nicely.

Comment: A oneliner: `sudo apt-get install -y xbindkeys xsel xdotool && echo '"echo -n | xsel -n -i; pkill xbindkeys; xdotool click 2; xbindkeys"' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc && echo 'b:2 + Release' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc && xbindkeys -p && echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nName=xbindkeys\nExec=xbindkeys\nComment=Disable middle click paste" >> ~/.config/autostart/xbindkeys.desktop`

Comment: Works great for preventing auto-paste, but even with the suggested patch by Kvothe, I can't scroll in programs like Krita. Autoscroll in Firefox still works, but programs where scroll is based on the middle mouse button being held aren't really compatible with this solution

Comment: Sadly, Xbindkeys isn't compatible with Wayland: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308479/transporting-xbindkeys-keyboard-shortcuts-to-wayland

Comment: I messes up Blender though

Comment: Thank you so much! This method is the only one that works for Chrome and Slack.

Answer (score 29):

Scrollwheel mice support a middle-button click event when pressing the scrollwheel. This is a great feature, but you may find it irritating. Fortunately it can be disabled.

First, you need to know the id of the mouse, like this:

```
$ xinput list | grep 'id='
```

which prints something like

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜ PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse       id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My Dell Usb mouse has printed here for which id=12

so, I can view the my mouse button mapping like:

```
$ xinput get-button-map 12
```

which prints

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

here only the first three numbers have meaning for me. They represent the left, middle, and right mouse buttons.

I can turn the middle mouse button off by setting it to 0:

```
$ xinput set-button-map 12 1 0 3
```

Or I can turn the middle-mouse button into a left-mouse button by setting it to 1:

```
$ xinput set-button-map 12 1 1 3
```

> ref. link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input

it works for me ( kubuntu 18.04 LTS )

Comment: This is a better than any of the above that start with "download XX". The only issue I had is that for `xinput set-button-map 12 1 0 3` you set all the buttons (1 - 12 for in this exampe  `xinput set-button-map 12 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`)

Comment: Note that you can find which button is which by pressing it and holding it down (then deleting any pasted text) then (with it still held down), type `xinput query-state 12` (or whatever xinput id your mouse is, if it isn't 12), you can then see that only that button is down and you can disable it. I'm pretty sure this will disable middle mouse button functionality *everywhere*, not just for pasting, but this is what I wanted, I never use the middle mouse button because it's too sensitive. This does not affect the mouse wheel, though.

Comment: Note that `xinput list | grep 'id='` has a different id at each reboot. So adding something to the bash start up script would need to process this. I don't have the bash script-fu skills to do this. Maybe someone does and can provide a link to their script?

Comment: This kills middle click, not middle click paste.

Comment: Killing middle click completely with only standard tools is perfect for the touchpad on my laptop  (where much of what feels like the left button is detected as middle). It's also simpler than disabling Firefox's middle click on a tab to close it. So have a great big +1 from me.

Answer (score 23):

In Fedora 24 you can install `gnome-tweak-tool` using the following command:

```
$ sudo dnf install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open `gnome-tweak-tool` and go to the "Keyboard and Mouse" tab and disable "Middle-click-Paste".

Comment: This is also available in Ubuntu 16.04:

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: This only affects a few programs such as gedit, gnome-terminal and a few others. See also comment at https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste.

Comment: In Fedora 33, while disabled in tweak tool, middle click paste still is enabled in google chrome.

Comment: after updating my Gnome extensions today its not working

Comment: Doesn't do anything on my Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 13):

## Solution for both Wayland and X11 users

This script will disable middle mouse paste, it supports both Wayland and X11, and you will still be able to use the middle mouse button normally:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script to disable middle mouse paste; Dependencies: xsel, wl-clipboard

if [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" == "wayland" ]; then
    wl-paste -p --watch wl-copy -p </dev/null # Usually works.
    #wl-paste -p --watch wl-copy -cp  # 100% Effective, may cause issues selecting text in GTK applications.
fi

while [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" == "x11" ]; do
    xsel -fin </dev/null    # 100% Effective, May cause issues selecting text in GTK applications.
done
```

Old Answer (A way for X11 that shouldn't cause issues with text selection in GTK): https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/472464/6

## Update: Fighting GTK's bugs!

So I noticed that some applications on Wayland will only clear the primary clipboard if you use the `wl-copy -cp` route (looking at you! chromium!), but that breaks selection in GTK applications. Now the ideal solution was if the GTK devs fixed their broken shit, but nobody has time to wait for that, so I figured out a workaround (it's not pretty, but it works) for this problem, unfortunately however on wayland this is, and can only ever be a compositor specific solution which means I can't give everyone the perfect solution, but luckily the concept is extremely simple and it's only 4 lines of code so anyone should be able to figure out how to modify it for their machine.

Here is the workaround for Hyprland:

1. First, we disable the primary clipboard for the problematic GTK applications:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
   ```
2. Obtain this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   applist="thunar gedit kitty"

   #If current window is not in the applist, clear primary clipboard
   if ! hyprctl -j activewindow | jq .class | grep -Ei "$(echo $applist | sed 's: :\|:g')" >/dev/null; then
       wl-copy -cp
   fi
   ```
3. Edit for your compositor. If you are not on Hyprland, then you need to replace this snippet: `hyprctl -j activewindow | jq .class` with something that will spit out the class of your currently active window.
4. Add any apps which have selection problems to the applist in the script:

   ```
   applist="gedit thunar mousepad gparted pcmanfm and so on"
   ```

   These apps need to be a good match for the identifier you are using to find these windows in the script(in this case the value shown for 'class' by `hyprctl activewindow`)
5. Execute the script:

   ```
   wl-paste -p --watch /path/to/the/script
   ```

In theory the same could be done on X11 using `xprops` instead of `hyprctl activewindow`, and replacing `wl-copy -cp` with `xsel -cp` but I have not tested it yet, I will probably update this answer later once I do.

Comment: This still lets you use middle mouse for scrolling. Good solution! 
For me the file was in `~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc`

Comment: Thank you! it's working for Manjaro & KDE with `echo -n | xsel -z`

Answer (score 12):

Having the middle button paste is a unix user interface standard, like having the left button select or activate, and the right button do something else (such as extending, toggling, firing up a menu, …). You'll find it bound to pasting in most unix applications.

If your problem is that your mouse is overly sensitive when you put your finger on the wheel, I suggest getting a better mouse. There are plenty of cheap decent mice.

You can reassign mouse button 2 to a different number. Applications identify the left, middle and right mouse buttons as buttons 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Put this code in a script that's executed when your X session starts (how to do that depends on your desktop environment).

```
echo 'pointer = 1 6 3 4 5' | xmodmap -
```

Comment: I'm betting OP doesn't care if it is standard (I know I don't). Doesn't matter. Mouse button actions should be more easily customizable.

Comment: Good answer. In my case, a variant is need: echo 'pointer = 1 0' | xmodmap -

Comment: "I suggest getting a better mouse" -- Unfortunately mice both cheap and expensive tend to have hair trigger mouse wheels, I don't know why. My 50 USD gaming mouse that's otherwise very good will happily middle click while scrolling with *slightly* more vigor than usual. It's not even a distinct *click*, it's a mushy sort of squish click, so I don't even know it happened. As a lefty unfortunately I don't have a lot of choices. This was the only mouse I could use in the store with more than 3 buttons.... it's not just me either, colleagues using standard Dell mice had issues with this too.

Comment: @jrh My favorite mouse has a thumb button. It also has a wheel that's good enough not to be pressed by accident, but I rarely press it, because I use the thumb button. I doubt they make it anymore: it must be about 20 years old. It's very asymmetric though, I don't know if a left-handed version exists, that does unfortunately limit choices a lot.

Comment: Funny enough until I found [Suraj](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487975/144785)'s answer I was seriously considering disabling middle click everywhere through a driver if available, or in the worst case, mechanically altering the mouse to try and prevent the button from even functioning, luckily it didn't come to that.

Comment: @jrh My answer does the same thing as Suraj with a different tool. The advantage of Suraj's answer is that `xinput` lets you configure separate pointing devices separately, unlike `xmodmap`.

Comment: This is *not* a solution and will break all middle mouse functionality. The question asked to disable middle click paste, not middle click.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** I just found an issue with the solution I've posted: in some programs (`gitk` at least, not sure how common it is) this will prevent text selection from working. So try it, but if you have problems with selecting text in a program you use regularly, then the solution is to stop using this.

Install `xsel`, and then run the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    xsel -fin </dev/null
done
```

As long as this script is running (you can set it to run on login) the middle mouse button will not paste in any application. So technically it will still paste, but there will always be nothing to paste.

The way it works is it runs `xsel` and has it copy (`-i`) the contents of `/dev/null`, without forking to the background (`-n`), and to actually hold that empty string in the buffer instead of just clearing it and exiting (`-f`). Every time it exits, it will invoke `xsel` again with the same options. Since `xsel` will keep running until another program "relieves it of duty" by copying something else, it won't constantly create new processes, instead keeping a single process running precisely until it is needed again. (Unless you have multiple instances of the script running, but there's no need to do that.)

Also no, this won't interfere with regular copy/paste, because the middle-click paste uses a separate clipboard.

Comment: This solution is amazing! Seriously, this is the best solution here! It completely blocks middle mouse pasting without interfering with normal pasting at all and it doesn't mess with the middle mouse button's other functionality in any way!

Comment: It does work on wayland, but uses a whopping 10% of CPU load on a thinkpad t480s during regular tasks. As I understand it should just run once and then be stuck? 
I added `sleep 1` and could not find any drawbacks to this yet.
Wondering why not use `xsel -pc` instead of copying /dev/null?

Comment: This will still "paste" the empty string right? So if I select some text and then hit the middle mouse button it will effectively delete the selected text, or not?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the @flarn2006 answer, I have created a daemon switch and a simple eraser:

## Requirements

`xsel`, `notify-send`, and a shortcuts manager (in my case is `xfce4-keyboard-setting`)

### First create a `.middle-paste/` folder  in `$HOME` and add two files:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# toggler.sh

# Set the lock file and program paths
PROGRAM_PATH="$HOME/.middle-paste/"
LOCKER_FILE="$PROGRAM_PATH/lock"

# Check if there is a lock file
if [ -f "$LOCKER_FILE" ]; then
    # If exists, read the PID of the daemon, which is contained inside the file
    daemon_pid=$(cat $LOCKER_FILE)

    # Then kill the daemon
    kill "$daemon_pid"

    # And delete delete the lock
    rm $LOCKER_FILE

    notify-send --urgency=critical --expire-time=500 \
    'Middle Mouse Paste Disabled' \
    'There could be some troubles handling the middle mouse button in some apps.'
else
    # If the file does not exist, create it
    edit > $LOCKER_FILE

    # Then run the daemon to disable middle click pasting
    sh $PROGRAM_PATH/daemon.sh &

    # A little pause
    sleep 0.1s

    # Get the daemon PID to show it in the notification
    daemon_pid=$(cat $LOCKER_FILE)

    notify-send --urgency=critical --expire-time=500 \
    "Middle Mouse Paste Enabled ("$daemon_pid")" \
    'There could be some troubles selecting text in some apps.'
fi
```

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# daemon.sh

# Set the lock file and program paths
PROGRAM_PATH="$HOME/.middle-paste/"
LOCKER_FILE="$PROGRAM_PATH/lock"

# Append the PID of this process the lock file
echo $$ > $LOCKER_FILE

# Run the daemon
while true; do
    xsel -fin < /dev/null
done
```

### Second configure the switcher

It can be a launcher, a button in your panel, or even a shortcut, you only need to

1. **Add `sh $HOME/.middle-paste/toggler.sh` to a `SUPR + X` shortcut** to quickly toggle the daemon. Please substitute the `$HOME` variable with your real home path or the Shortcut Manager could fail finding the script (eg. `/home/user/.middle-paste/toggle.sh`)
2. **Add `xsel -c` to a `SUPR + V` shortcut** to clear the middle mouse clipboard quickly without the need of a daemon. This is useful when you know that you will not get out of the application where you will not copy, but you will use the middle mouse button (Like `Figma` or `Inkscape`, where this issue is problematic only when there are something in the clipboard already).

Answer (score 1):

It's a common convention that many programs abide by.  There is no global way to turn it off, you must do it on a program by program basis.

EDIT: (short of, as Gilles says, disabling mouse button 2.  But some programs do have other uses for mouse button 2, so I would not recommend this.)

Answer (score 1):

With KDE an additional step may be required to solve the problem.

It seems that Klipper, the clipboard manager provided by KDE, breaks the scripts that fix the behavior by clearing the clipboard selection.

The following will globally disable paste on middle click while retaining all middle mouse button and ctrl+c/v functionality.

Follow the steps described in [Radivarig's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277488/406769), that is:

> 1. Install `xbindkeys xsel xdotool`
> 2. Place this in `~/.xbindkeysrc`
>
>    ```
>    "echo -n | xsel -n -i; pkill xbindkeys; xdotool click 2; xbindkeys"  
>    b:2 + Release
>    ```
> 3. Reload `xbindkeys -p`

In step 2. you may need to remove the  `+ Release` part as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144039/1008543), depending on what works on your machine.

Then open Klipper, e.g. via the clipboard icon in the system tray > right click > Configure Clipboard. **Uncheck the option 'Prevent empty clipboard'.** Reboot and the problem should be solved.

The idea of the latter is thanks to [milaq's XMousePasteBlock](https://github.com/milaq/XMousePasteBlock).

Comment: works, but with the caveat that it will try to paste an empty text, so if you have something selected, that's gone.

Answer (score 1):

I've been coding for decades but mainly on a Windows machine.  Only recently I've been delving into the world of coding under Linux and now I've run into this annoyance - my most recent project was peppered with random text because the middle button on the mouse I was using was rather sensitive - I was totally stumped until decide to google the issue and landed here.

I have never intentionally used the middle button to click anything ever, perhaps because it doesn't do anything in Windows by default.  I have only ever used the middle scroll wheel to scroll.  After reading a few of the various solutions on the web and in this thread, I've decided on a simpler solution.

Here it is:

1. Unplug the mouse from the USB port.
2. Go get a #1 phillips screw driver and a pair of electronic side-cutters
3. Look under the mouse and find the screw to open the bottom cover.
4. Remove the screw and remove the cover.
5. Find the little microswitch that is underneath the spring-loaded scroll wheel arm.
6. Use the side-cutters to crush that switch and cut off the guts of it.  Try not to damage the optical wheel and sensors.  Enjoy the feeling of getting your revenge for having to scan through all your code for random bits of text.
7. Clean out the debris and re-assemble the mouse.
8. Plug the mouse back into the USB port.
9. Observe the scroll wheel working.  Try to click the middle mouse button - oh look, nothing happens!

Aaaahhhhh!  That's much better!

p.s. You can use this opportunity to clean out all the crud that builds up inside your mouse - your mouse will perform so much better now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KDE desktop manager, KDE Plasma 5.18 for example, you could open `Configure Desktop` in right-click menu at desktop window. Then check `Mouse Actions` to configure/remove the action for `Middle-Button`.

You can also refer to this tutorial for more information: [Detailed Guide to Configure KDE Plasma Desktop](https://technastic.com/configure-kde-plasma-desktop/).

PS: I have been puzzled over the default paste action of middle button for a long time. It is a bit weird that such configuration cannot be accessed in `System Settings`. And it is just be discovered accidentally. Hope it would help you if you are using KDE.

Comment: that doesnt actually seem to affect applications sadly

Answer (score 0):

I found yet another solution using [`sxhkd`](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd).

It disables plain middle click (without hold down a modifier key) for all XWayland applications, like Chromium, Konsole, Discord. (Maybe even all applications when using Xorg.)

This fix has no effect on real Wayland applications, like Terminal and Firefox (with Wayland enabled). For these, it is still needed to use something like [gnome-tweaks](/questions/24330/how-can-i-turn-off-middle-mouse-button-paste-functionality-in-all-programs/277488#301772) and [about-config](https://askubuntu.com/a/97309).

This solution also solves the problem of accidentally opening tabs with random links when using a thinkpad trackpoint keyboard II to scroll on a webpage. Mine literately middle clicks every time I scroll.

Also, with the `echo -n | xsel -n -i` trick, the cursor position still changes when pasting a empty clipboard. This still can be really annoying when you just want to continue typing where you left off after some scrolling.

Another benefit of this fix is that the middle click paste functionality still works! You just need to hold down one of the modifier keys while middle clicking.

Install `sxhkd`:

```bash
sudo apt install sxhkd
```

Make a `sxhkd` config at `~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` (or append if one already exists) to capture middle click, without replaying it to the application:

```bash
mkdir ~/.config/sxhkd
# capture plain middle click with the no-op ':'
cat << EOF >> ~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc
button2
     :
EOF
```

Run `sxhkd`:

```bash
sxhkd
```

To automatically run `sxhkd` at startup, it can be added using 'Startup Applications', or use this command:

```bash
# run sxhkd at startup (this is the same as doing it manually via 'Startup Applications')
cat << EOF > ~/.config/autostart/sxhkd.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sxhkd
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=sxhkd
Comment=catch plain middle click in non Gnome apps
EOF
```

If you do a lot of horizontal scrolling by holding down shift, you can also add these lines to your config. Then also middle mouse clicks when holding down shift gets captured.

```
shift + button2
     :
```

EDIT: After some time using this solution, I found another really nice feature. Middle click on an unfocused XWayland window now just focuses it, without clicking! So you don't lose selected text or your cursor position, and you don't have to click carefully around all active areas. In Gnome this has the same effect as Super-Click or Alt-Tab.

Comment: For Wayland, [swhkd](https://github.com/waycrate/swhkd) may do the trick also for Gnome applications.