# Transporting Xbindkeys/Keyboard Shortcuts to Wayland?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wayland

I am currently using several dozen keyboard shortcuts in `xfce4` using `xbindkeys`. I want to switch to Wayland though for window management.

**Question:** Does `xbindkeys` work in Wayland? If not, how does one configure keyboard shortcuts in Wayland? Is there an easy way to transplant a keyboard setup from X to Wayland?

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to find out more about the possibilities for global keybindings in *Wayland*, but have seen mostly found inconsistent or incomplete information. `xbindkeys` will not work in *Wayland*, except (maybe) for *X* applications, which use an instance of *X* Server running as a *Wayland* client. Because the creators of *Wayland* are emphasizing greater security and compartmentalization of applications, there's been some resistance to enabling inter-client communication (such as that between `xbindkeys` and the focused window or the window manager, etc). Not sure exactly how it is/will be implemented, but I think it would involve privileging certain applications to send messages indirectly through the compositor (*Weston* or other). Could be wrong about that. Regardless, the *Wayland* API will be different, and thus require new keybinding programs. As of a couple months ago, it didn't appear any had been developed, and I'm not sure it had been settled how that sort of *IPC* would be handled.  Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a port of xbindkeys, but I think it provides similar functionality. Sadly the sway wiki does not really mention it but it is in the `man 5 sway`

```
mode <mode>
    Switches to the specified mode. The default mode is default.

mode [--pango_markup] <mode> <mode-subcommands...>
    The only valid mode-subcommands... are bindsym, bindcode, bindswitch, and set. If --pango_markup is
    given, then mode will be interpreted as pango markup.
```

it is also mentioned in the Arch Linux wiki [Control swaynag with the keyboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sway#Control_swaynag_with_the_keyboard) and in at least one issue ['mode --pango_markup' compatibility](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/663)).

I believe it works the same way that the i3 config does. I will be testing it soon. The i3 manual [Binding modes](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#binding_modes) section looks like the best source for learning to use this feature

Answer (score 0):

Not directly migrating the config, but for wayland I dropped my xbindkeys and switched to evdev described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587975/18775

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.