# Remapping mouse buttons in Wayland

Tags: mouse, wayland, libinput

I have two Logitech trackballs, a Wireless TrackMan FX and a Marble Mouse. Both report the same set of buttons in `evtest`: `BTN_LEFT`, `BTN_RIGHT`, `BTN_MIDDLE`, `BTN_SIDE` and `BTN_EXTRA` even though they only have four physical buttons each. The TrackMan FX sends the exact events I want: left, right, middle and side. However, the Marble Mouse sends `BTN_EXTRA` instead of `BTN_MIDDLE`, so I'd like to remap that.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587975/187221) seems to cover exactly what I want and hwdb looks like the right place to do it. Alas, it only works halfway and I have no idea why; I suspect it has to do with the two different input events generated by a single click. `evtest` reports a working middle click from the FX like this (leaving out irrelevant time stamps for clarity):

```
type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90003
type 1 (EV_KEY), code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE), value 1
```

The unmodified click from the MarbleMouse:

```
type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
type 1 (EV_KEY), code 276 (BTN_EXTRA), value 1
```

So my `99-marblebutton.hwdb` file does this:

```
evdev:input:b0003v046DpC408*
 ID_INPUT_KEY=1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_90005=btn_middle
```

And the resulting input event is modified thus:

```
type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
type 1 (EV_KEY), code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE), value 1
```

So I do get a `BTN_MIDDLE` event but the associated `MSC_SCAN` still has the wrong value, and that seems to make a difference as the middle click isn't recognized anywhere. In fact it doesn't even seem to be considered a valid input event at all: using `libinput debug-events` I can see the unmodified event:

```
event7   POINTER_BUTTON          +97.374s      BTN_EXTRA (276) pressed, seat count: 1
```

With the hwdb config in place, nothing is reported when I press the same button, and consequently `wev` doesn't see the events either.

Other things I've tried include remapping in swaywm which sort of works, but only in some applications:

```
set $MOUSE "1133:50184:Logitech_USB_Trackball"
bindsym --input-device=$MOUSE --whole-window BTN_EXTRA seat - cursor press BTN_MIDDLE
bindsym --input-device=$MOUSE --whole-window --release BTN_EXTRA seat - cursor release BTN_MIDDLE
```

[interception-tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) allow me to write a filter that can "fix" both the `EV_KEY` and the `EV_MSC` event, but the effect is similar to hwdb: the events show up fine in `evtest` but libinput doesn't even see them.

Solaar doesn't seem to support either of my devices, and I'm too thick to get input-remapper to do anything useful.