# Ubuntu Studio (KDE) middle-click doesn't work properly

Tags: ubuntu, kde, mouse

I've just installed Ubuntu Studio on my Lenovo Thinkpad, and noticed that the middle-click, both on the built-in touchpad as well as the hardware 'middle' button, isn't working properly. In Blender and Sketchup, where I should be able to orbit with the middle-button held-down, I get no response at all from a middle-click. When I test using `xev` I see the ButtonPress and ButtonRelease event registering, but ONLY after I 'release' the button. ie. it's not triggering on the actual 'press' part, just on the 'release', and at that time both events appear...

Would this be a driver issue? (other linux distros - MX and regular Ubuntu with Gnome) didn't have this issue... Or some other system setting?
So far I've tried this 'solution' [How can I turn off "middle mouse button paste" functionality in all programs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24330/how-can-i-turn-off-middle-mouse-button-paste-functionality-in-all-programs/686483#686483) but it  didn't have any affect one way or the other...

Thanks!
David